# How much of an html form can be altered without triggering CSRF protection?

Tags: php, html, forms, csrf

I implemented CSRF protection by including a token with PHP into a hidden input for every form. Each token can only be used once, of course.

However, there are tools, such as any web developer tools, which allow inputs to be changed. For example, I can change on-page input forms: I can make disabled checkboxes enabled, and I can change input boxes to textarea boxes without reloading the page or anything like that. CSRF wouldn't catch such changes.

So, how much of a form do I need to validate to stay safe? Do I need to validate every single input to make sure it wasn't altered, including selects, checkboxes, hidden inputs, etc? Surely it can't be safe to assume that these haven't been altered?

Comment: No, you can't be sure that anything that comes in through `$_POST` or `$_GET` hasn't been manipulated.

Comment: Never trust user supplied content. If it is important that a field is valid, then validate it. For instance an email address may be worth validating but a comments box may only need checking to see if its empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate (on the server side) everything that needs to be validated.  What exactly needs to be validated depends on many factors and personal choices.  Some of it may be for safety, but only a bare minimum is needed for that in many cases.  For the most part validation is to improve or create user experience.

For example you can check to see whether they have entered a valid email address.  If they haven't, you can give them a message.  If you don't do that nothing bad will happen to your application, but the user won't be able to receive email from you.

There is also an important distinction between ***validation*** and ***sanitation***.  Sanitation is done for security (e.g. to prevent injection).  Validation is done to make sure that input meets requirements to work correctly with your application although incorrect input may be benign.  It's also possible for sanitized malicious input to be valid.

***All*** input must be sanitized.  No input *needs* to be validated, so it's really up to you.

CSRF protection has nothing to do with validation.  All it does is prevent a user from making a request using your form from an external source because the only way to generate and see the token is to make a request to your site first.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Let me ask a quick example: if I want to allow a user to delete a post he made, I can make a form submit button that has the name="delete_post" and value="[#post_id]". Now, in order for the user to even SEE that button, he must be the owner of the post. In this case, once he presses the button, do I need to redo checks that he is the owner of "delete_post" value? Is it even possible to change this value to someone else's post? I feel like I just keep doing the same repetitive validations over and over again.

Comment: @user371699 yes you need to do the authentication check, but it should be fairly trivial to do.  For example, `DELETE FROM post WHERE user_id = ? AND id = ?`.  `user_id` is probably already in the session

Comment: No doubt it's trivial, but in my case, there are a lot of checks to do. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

What we are trying to do using CSRF is to ensure that the request IS coming from a reliable source. For e.g, your case what you need to do is ensure that the value in the hidden field is sane. And it can be sane (provided that your token is strong enough) only if it is the same as the one that was provided while the form was rendered by the server.

Now whether fields in the form changed or not, is just your application logic. It does not have anything to do with csrf. If the token is sane, then it came from the right source. Now, if it was the same person who entered values in the form for e.g. is not within the scope of csrf.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the wrong end of the stick here. The token is not a hash of the form when it was sent.

The way this works is to store your unique token in a hidden field on the form and into the session when you server the original page.

When you get the page POSTed/GETed back from your user you check that the token on the page is the same as the token previously stored in the session.

Changing fields must still be allowed or your user will not be able to enter any data on the form. You are just checking that you got the same form back that you sent, because the token is the same, rather than one from somewhere else, i.e. its not a cross site request forgery.

You still have to validate all the fields and do any data preparing before storing it in a database.

[Reading1](http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/php-security-measures-against-csrf-attacks/) 
[Reading2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)